# Bootstrap 4 modal not displaying

Tags: bootstrap-4

My boostrap modal would not show. When I click edit button, it would not show the modal but only the shadow background.

Edit button code

```
<button type="button" class="edit-modal btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-firstname="{{ $user->firstname }}" data-lastname="{{ $user->lastname }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">Edit</span>
</button>
```

Edit modal code

```
<!-- EDIT MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-contetn">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        @if(isset($user))
            {!! Form::model($user, ['route' => ['user.update', $user->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}

                {!! Form::hidden('id', null, ['id' => 'edit-user-id']) !!}

                {!! Form::label('First Name:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('firstname', null, ['id' => 'edit-user-firstname', 'class' => "form-control"]) !!}

                {!! Form::label('Last Name:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('lastname', null, ['id' => 'edit-user-firstname', 'class' => "form-control"]) !!}


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top:20px" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        {!! Form::submit('Save Changes', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'style' => 'margin-top:20px']) !!}
      </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
      @endif
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END EDIT MODAL -->
```

Javascript code

```
$(function() {
    $('.edit-modal').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var firstname = $(this).data('firstname');
        var lastname = $(this).data('lastname');

        $('#edit-user-id').val(id);
        $('#edit-user-firstname').val(firstname);
        $('#edit-user-lastname').val(lastname);

    });
});
```

It seems my code is correct but I do not know why it does not show. Maybe I just miss something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo and this is the problem.

`<div class="modal-contetn">` in HTML line 4.

You have `conteTN` instead of `conteNT`.

If you want to avoid further mistakes just copy paste templates from bootstrap site. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/

**EDIT:**
If you fix the typo it should work. Check out if the tag `@endif`is placed correctly. I can't check the Laravel part.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<button type="button" class="edit-modal btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal">
    Open modal
</button>

<!-- EDIT MODAL -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END EDIT MODAL -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the debug. After I correct the error, still it doesn't display only a shadow background

Comment: I removed `if...endif` part and it works. Loot at the `@endif` tag. Shouldn't it be inside `modal-body`?

Comment: Still doesn't show and I copy paste your code to try it. By the way, I use datatables and and I store the edit button inside the <td>.

Comment: Did you place modal at the end of the page? Modals CAN'T be placed in a container but directly inside `<body>` tag.

Comment: Yes it works now. Normally I place it inside the container. Thank you. Thumbs up!